# How to change the position of the toast notification in windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to change the position of the toast notification in windows 10. Instead of on the bottom, i want it to appear on the top for instance. I found a trick to change in the registry. I wanted to do it programatically in c++. Does anyone know how i can do that?

Comment: ...and the registry entry is?

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
DisplayToastAtBottom

Comment: Can't you have your c++ application modify the registry?

Comment: I just thought there is a way via COM interfaces without changing th registry

Comment: That registry entry doesn't work anymore since the RTM version of Windows 10.

Comment: Changing registry via C++ is trivial, finding a working registry key now is a problem...